# Is it possible to forbid dependencies in class using annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I need to prevent importing classes from some package in some of classes of my java8 project.
Is it possible to create some kind of annotation like @NoSomePackage to check if there are forbidden imports in the class and break compilation if there are?

Comment: You can only decorate the class itself using `@Deprecated` with a meaningful message. But what you want seems hacky to me. Why do you want to do that? Don´t you trust the guy who created the package?

Comment: If you use Maven, you can ban certain dependencies from your project as a whole - https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html.  You cannot prevent specific imports within a class though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you are in controll of that package you import from. If some classes should not be importable from outside world, consider making them private or package private (no access modifier).

If you are not in controll of that package and you still need to forbid to import some classes, consider creatign and using some kind of facade instead of that target package, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern. It is not bulletproof solution, but it would increase the chances you will not use that class by misstake.

As far as I know, there is no possibility forbid importing a visible class on the classpath.